# i want different between current year and given year in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

i am want get different of number in years:

For example : 2021-2010 = 11

So i am doing similar as my code:

```
{{assign currentYear = 'now' | date: "%Y"}}{{ assign AllYears = currentYear | minus: 2010 }}
```

But its show only `-2010`.

So please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?
(not tested)

```
{% assign currentYear = 'now' | date: "%Y" | plus:0 %}
{% assign AllYears = currentYear | minus: 2010 %}
{{ AllYears }}
```